# Secure random number of aproximately given size

Tags: java, random, cryptography, biginteger

I'm doing a Secret Sharing algorithm which encrypts a a message. To do that I need a bigger than message prime and some random numbers of aproximately the same size as the message.

I can do the first with BigInteger.probablePrime(MsgSize+8) but I do not know how to do the later.

I was using Random and later SecureRandom but they don't generate numbers of a given length. My solution was to do randomInt ^ randomInt to BigInteger but is obviously a bad solution.

Some ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but wouldn't the constructor `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(MsgSize, new SecureRandom());` do the trick?

Comment: I hadn't thought on the constructor. But the only that seems suitable is new BigInteger(bitLength, certainity, new SecureRandom), the only proble I see is I do not need the overhead of checking whether it is prime.

Comment: @millimoose Your's is the answer I used but I checked Sinan Cepel's because I used simply a commend. Very good one, though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the same probablePrime method with a smaller size, then using a large random integer as an offset from that number? That might do the trick, just an idea.

Comment: I guess that's a good option too, even whithout the offset. As I said on top, the only proble I see is I do not need the overhead of checking whether it is prime.

Answer (score 4):

Is it [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) that you're implementing?  If so, note that you don't actually need a prime bigger than the entire message — it's perfectly fine to break the message into chunks of some manageable size and to share each chunk separately using a fixed prime.

Also, Shamir's Secret Sharing doesn't need a prime-sized field; it's possible to use any [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) GF(p<sup>n</sup>), including in particular the binary fields GF(2<sup>n</sup>).  Such fields are particularly convenient for computer implementation, since the both the secret and share chunks will then be simply n-bit bitstrings.

The only complications are that, in non-prime fields, you'll have to implement [finite field arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) (or find an existing implementation) and that you'll need to choose a particular reducing polynomial and agree upon it.  However, the former isn't really as complicated as it might seem, and the latter isn't really any harder than choosing and agreeing on a prime.  (In particular, a reducing polynomial for GF(2<sup>n</sup>) can be naturally represented as an n-bit bitstring, dropping the high bit which is always 1.)

Comment: Indeed is SSS what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your, answer. I used a prime sized field because I was said It was safer. Indeed I split the secret in chunks and then I look for a prime bigger than this chunk, so it will be bigger than any chunk. This can be kind of wierd, but It's a educational demo so it's nice to see that the prime grows with the chunk size.

Comment: That's an interesting claim (about a prime field being safer), given that SSS in _any_ finite field is information-theoretically secure, provided that the random numbers used are truly random, independent and uniform. If anything, generating uniform random numbers modulo a power of 2 tends to be easier on a computer than doing so modulo a prime.

Comment: I learned it on a subject about security where the teacher used to love prime numbers as safest. In fact I based my algorithm in other that used a safe prime number generated with open_ssl. I supose you know, but for clarification a safe primer number is a primer number 2n+1 where n is prime number too(I think it's called strong prime number too).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (thats why i found this post). 
It is a little late but maybe someone else finds this method usefull:

```
public static BigDecimal getBigRandom(int d)
{
    BigDecimal rnd = new BigDecimal(Math.random());

    BigDecimal rndtmp;

    for(int i=0;i<=d;i++)
    {
        rndtmp = new BigDecimal(Math.random());
        rndtmp = rndtmp.movePointLeft(rnd.precision());
        rnd = rnd.add(rndtmp);
    }    

    return rnd;
}
```

Usage: 
BigDecimal x = getBigRandom(y);

every y will give you approximately 50 digits.

if you need more than (2^31-1)*50 digits simply change int to long ;-)

dont know if it is good, but works for me

Comment: It seems a bit inefficient to me. At the end I used SecureRandom instead of Random and used BigInteger's probablePrime(numDigits, accuracy) to get a number of aproximate numDigits digits in a reasonably quick time.